# Use WildFly module both datasource and connectionFactory

Tags: java, wildfly, jaybird

I have a module in Wildfly to use as my datasource to Firebird. It works great

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.firebirdsql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jaybird-2.2.13.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/> <!-- Jaybird 3.0 onwards doesn't need this -->
        <module name="org.antlr4"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and the jar is put inside the directory of module.xml.

But I want to use the driver both with data source and also to create a pure JDBC connection in connectionfactory like `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");`, not using data source provided by the server.

If I put jaybird in pom.xml I got errors. I think because this is duplicating the libs. How can I solve this?

Comment: With Jaybird 3.0.0 and up it is not necessary to declare the dependency on `javax.xml.bind.api`; I removed that dependency between 3.0.0-beta-3 and 3.0.0.

Comment: I edited my post to alert this, thank you!

Comment: Just saw your edit, but Jaybird 2.2 also doesn't require `javax.xml.bind.api`, it was just the test versions of Jaybird 3; I decided last minute to remove that dependency entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the below code under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">`

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="org.firebirdsql" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

Thanks, Mark Rotteveel for answer on the [Jaybird bug tracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-501).